# Автоматический запуск загрузки файла в БД

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите скрипт или как поправить [Sypex Dumper](http://sypex.net/ru/products/dumper/features) . Есть Интернет магазин. В корень FTP будут ложиться сформированные в 1С файлы формата csv или xls. Нужно, что бы, например, раз в день скрипт брал файл с сервера и загонял его в SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно запускать с помощью cron.
Предварительно нужно создать задачу, которая будет выполняться.
[Пример экспорта](http://4udak.com/zapusk-sypex-dumper-cherez-cron-avtomaticheskij-backup.html) импорт делается аналогично.